# Анимация JS в качестве фона для блока

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas

Никак не соображу, как поставить анимацию фоном для блока div. При этом, поверх должны располагаться различные объекты (текст, картинка, кнопка). Пробовал z-index-ом, но безуспешно. Ко всему прочему, в идеале, хорошо бы вместо цветового тона на фоне в анимации вставить картинку, либо прозрачный фон, чтобы только падающие буквы были.

```js
const s = window.screen;
const w = (q.width = s.width);
const h = (q.height = s.height);
const ctx = q.getContext("2d");

const p = Array(Math.floor(w / 10) + 1).fill(0);

const random = (items) => items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];

const hex = "0123456789ABCDEF".split("");

setInterval(() => {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,25,80,.05)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#143170";
  p.map((v, i) => {
    ctx.fillText(random(hex), i * 10, v);
    p[i] = v >= h || v > 50 + 10000 * Math.random() ? 0 : v + 10;
  });
}, 3000 / 30);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<body>
  <div class="full-slider">
    <canvas id="q"></canvas>
    <h2>Системный интегратор</h2>
    <h4>в сфере информационной безопасности</h4>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Ваша информационная безопасность в нашем приоритете!</li>
        <li>Выявим, устраним, обеспечим защиту!</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Связь с экспертом</li>
        <li><button>Подробнее</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://vkclub.su/_data/stickers/zuck/sticker_vk_zuck_033.png" width="150">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так?

```
   canvas {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -10;
    }
```

```js
const s = window.screen;
const w = (q.width = s.width);
const h = (q.height = s.height);
const ctx = q.getContext("2d");

const p = Array(Math.floor(w / 10) + 1).fill(0);

const random = (items) => items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];

const hex = "0123456789ABCDEF".split("");

setInterval(() => {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,25,80,.05)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#143170";
  p.map((v, i) => {
    ctx.fillText(random(hex), i * 10, v);
    p[i] = v >= h || v > 50 + 10000 * Math.random() ? 0 : v + 10;
  });
}, 3000 / 30);
```

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<body>
  <div class="full-slider">
    <canvas id="q"></canvas>
    <h2>Системный интегратор</h2>
    <h4>в сфере информационной безопасности</h4>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Ваша информационная безопасность в нашем приоритете!</li>
        <li>Выявим, устраним, обеспечим защиту!</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Связь с экспертом</li>
        <li><button>Подробнее</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://vkclub.su/_data/stickers/zuck/sticker_vk_zuck_033.png" width="150">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Да, то что нужно... Спасибо! Я тоже ставил z-index -10 но видимо из-за отсутствия position он не срабатывал...

Comment: z-index то срабатывал. Просто канвас не был абсолютно позиционирован относительно других объектов, и они все выстраивались внизу.